# Get autocomplete selector after ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the selector of a jquery autocomplete in the "success" after making an ajax call.  In the "success" I am looking for $(this) to be $(".itemDescInput") but it is not.  How would I find that selector at that point?

```
$(".itemDescInput").autocomplete({
    source: "invoices/invoice_items.php",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var $it_desc = ui.item.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "invoices/invoice_items_prices.php",
            data: "it_desc="+$it_desc,
            success: function(result){
                if(result != '') {
                    $(this).find("input .itemCostEach").val(result);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `success()`, `this` does not refer to your selector but to your **AJAX settings**. You can change what `this` points to by setting **context** in your `ajax()` call. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

For example:

```
    $.ajax({
        context: this,  // You could pass 'this' in directly if you wanted :)
        success: function(result) {
            // Refer to 'this' in the way you expect
        }
    });
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was missing!  Thanks!

Comment: Or you can also try creating a variable referring to $(this) immediately as first statement in select and then refer to the variable in success callback of ajax.